# .NET Read ReportParameter from Local report

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

Is there a way to retrieve the local parameter we set using

```
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("UserComments", _userComments));
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you added "UserComments" as a parameter on the report? And set the report up using LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath; ?

Comment: And does _userComments definitely have a value?

Comment: Have you added "UserComments" as a parameter on the report? - YES And set the report up using LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath; ? - NO I did this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "EBT.App_Code.Report1.rdlc";

Comment: And does _userComments definitely have a value? - YES.  They show up in the footer of the reportviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LinQ you can do this:

```
    List<ReportParameterInfo> parameters = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters().Where(t => t.Name == "UserComments").ToList();
    ReportParameterInfo userCommentsParams = parameters[0];
    string comments = userCommentsParams.Values[0];
```

Comment: ReportParameterInfo is not very useful.  I am unable to retrieve the value I set earlier from this object.

Comment: This code throws Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameterInfo>' to 'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameterInfoCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Projects\AccessTools\Src\EBT\EBT\frmReport.cs 103 56 EBT ERROR.  If I cast it as a ReportParameterInfoCollection then it returns 'parametes' as NULL

Comment: @w69rdy    I am running VS2010 / .NET 4.0   No idea why this doesn't seem to work.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @capton My bad, fixed now. Yeah seems strange, other than that I don't know what to suggest...

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to use LINQ.  This is both cleaner and faster *(and works on pre-3.5 versions of .Net)*:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters()["UserComments"].Values[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the parameters in Code you can use the GetParameters class:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters()
```

Comment: tried it before... doesn't work.  It only returns the ParameterInfo collection and the ParameterInfo.Values[index] items don't have the value I set.  Strange